# yq omit document dividers (---) in result

Tags: yq

In yq 4.11.2, If I do this:

```sh
echo '---\nfoo: foo\n---\nfoo: foo\n' | yq eval '.foo' -
```

I get this:

```sh
foo
---
foo
```

Using yq only (not grep, awk, etc.), how can I remove the `---` to get this?

```sh
foo
foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with your `echo` invocation, that it does not expand literal newline characters by default, unless you run with `echo -e` or enable `xpg_echo` shell option if you are running this on bash/zsh

[mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) implementation has a mode `-N` that prints the filter output with out the document separators See `yq --help` when tested on version 4.13.3

```
echo -e '---\nfoo: foo\n---\nfoo: foo\n' | yq -N e '.foo' -
foo
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

In powershell

short answer:

```bash
$yaml_content -replace "---",""
```

practical use case:
I wanted to identify duplicate objects in my cluster manifest

```bash
# foreach document collect kind, name, namespace into an array. Default namespace to null.
$select_fields=$cluster_manifest_yaml | yq '[ { "kind" : .kind , "name" : .metadata.name , "namespace" : .metadata.namespace // null } ]'

# remove doc separator. Reduce to single array.
$separator_removed=$select_fields -replace '---',''

# convert yaml array to pscustomobject array
$countable_array=$separator_removed | yq -o json | ConvertFrom-Json

# display duplicate objects in array
$countable_array | Group-Object kind,namespace,name | Select-Object Name,Count | Where-Object Count -gt 1
```